# auth.log: systemd Log Spam, suspend.target is masked

Tags: systemd

With my server I have noticed that systemd is spamming the auth.log file with GBs of this:

```
Jan 29 15:40:14 server systemd-logind[438]: Suspending...
Jan 29 15:40:14 server systemd-logind[438]: Failed to execute operation: Unit suspend.target is masked.
```

Any idea how I can fix this? It is a laptop with suspension disabled and the lid closed. After a few days of the spam the disk is full and requires me to delete the files and reboot.

Answer (score 11):

There is a setting in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` that tells `systemd-logind` how to handle the laptop lid switch event.  Try setting `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` and restart systemd-logind.

And un-comment the line before saving.